# IEEE reference style - Bibtex format

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

I'm trying to get my references to the following format for an IEEE journal.

[image]

What is the correct way to do this in Latex?

My MWE is as below

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,aps,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,tightenlines,notitlepage,11pt,pra]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

Paper content

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

And a sample entry from my biblio file is below

```
@article{devetak2005private,
    Author = {Devetak, Igor},
    Journal = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {44--55},
    Publisher = {IEEE},
    Title = {The private classical capacity and quantum capacity of a quantum channel},
    Volume = {51},
    Year = {2005}}
```

Currently, the journal and conference names are not abbreviated as desired. How can I fix this?

Comment: In general BibTeX itself has very limited functionality when it comes to abbreviating journal names. Some styles have some support, but that requires compatible input (you need to use a special identifier instead of the literal journal title). If you need all your journals abbreviated you may be better off using an external tool to edit your `.bib` file. I think JabRef has an extensive journal abbreviation database.

Comment: Or if you use `biblatex` you can use the source map function to do replacement. But you still need to create a list of all the abbreviations. See [Show journal abbreviation in reference list with biblatex/biber](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/76241) for an example.  There is an IEEE style for `biblatex` so this might be an option for you.  But there's no general way to do this for an arbitrary journal name.

Comment: @moewe, thanks - I haven't used JabRef before but am I correct in understanding that I can take a .bib file with entries as in my question and use JabRef to generate a new .bib file with abbreviations for the journal names?

Comment: Yes, that's more or less the idea. See https://docs.jabref.org/advanced/journalabbreviations for more details.